# BrowserSync proxy on remote server with Gulp?

Tags: nginx, proxy, gulp, browser-sync

I have a remote Linux server that I'm running a Node.js app on, that is proxy'ed through nginx at `http://www.example.com`.

I have `gulp` (for SASS compiling) installed with BrowserSync. Whenever I start up `gulp` on the server, the access urls are something like this:

```
[BS] Access URLs:
 ----------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://10.0.2.15:3000
 ----------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://10.0.2.15:3001
 ----------------------------------
```

So, that's not going to work, cause I'm not trying to access the server via localhost. I need to access it at it's actual url: `http://www.example.com`. When I browse to `http://www.example.com` I can see in the page that BrowserSync is not injected into the page.

I have been messing with the BrowserSync proxy options but they are not clear. I tried the following in my `gulp` task:

```
browserSync.init({
  proxy: {
    target: 'http://www.example.com:4000'
  }
});
```

And then I get this:

```
[BS] Proxying: http://www.example.dev:4000
[BS] Access URLs:
 ----------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://10.0.2.15:3000
 ----------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://10.0.2.15:3001
 ----------------------------------
```

But port 4000 isn't open on the firewall, so that isn't going to work. Is this the right way to do it and I just need to open that port? Why wouldn't it work with port 80? Or am I way off on this?

Comment: I am also interested in this topic... Did you find a solution eventually?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this generator:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angular-proxy

It does exactly what you want...